# where property.setting value stored in c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I thought it should be a config file, but cannot find it.
thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're talking about .Net settings, then they will normally be in a .config (xml) file in the same directory as the application.  When you save them, however, a local copy gets saved in to a user writable folder (typically C:\Users\username\AppData\Local under Vista).  Under XP, look in the Documents and Settings folder.

The .Net application uses this file in preference to the 'default' one in the application directory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 53):

The whole config file location can be a bit slippery. Depending on whether or not its a "user" setting or an "application" setting, it will go into a different file. Some settings can even come from your "machine" config (Like in the case of ASP.NET). Instead of guessing where everything is, I find it much more useful to **ask .NET where it is looking for these files**. Roughly:

```
//Machine Configuration Path
string path1 = ConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration().FilePath;
//Application Configuration Path
string path2 = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( 
      ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;
//User Configuration Path 
string path3 = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
      ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath;
```

### App.Config

This is what gets added to your project. The build process will name it **[myproject].exe.config**. This holds the (mostly) read only application settings and the application-level defaults for user-specific settings. Application level settings are difficult to programmatically change their values. Application level setting properties will only have "get" defined. **The intention is:** *if your setting is for all users of the application, then a manual edit (or the installer) should set them. If it changes per user, then make it a per-user setting.*

### Binary Default Settings

Your application will run without its [myproject].exe.config file. To do this, the binary has its own version of the file "stored". This is useful in some ways, but can be confusing. If you have a .config file in the wrong place or with the wrong name, .NET reverts to the "binary defaults". It can cause the appearance of not being able to affect the settings by changing the config file. Use the method above to know where the .config REALLY goes, or face the wrath of the binary default settings.

### User.Config

This is generated the first time you "save" your Default.Settings object with a "per-user" setting. This file is saved in the user's profile path in a location based on your project's name, version, operating system, and *some other dark .NET magics*. The properties for these settings are readable/writeable. They are designed to be easily set and then saved with a single call.

### Pulling it Together

So where do my settings go? The answer is that potentially many files are joined together to get the "Active set" of settings. App.config and user.config settings are the basic blocks, but there are machine.config settings, and then there are dependency assembly settings that can further complicate things...but thats another topic entirely.

The real truth of config files is *spread across a lot of ugly cases and details*. However, with a little knowledge about how they are joined together, it is a fairly useful system. Especially if you realize you can databind to these settings ;)

Comment: +1 for a very thorough and useful answer and for making me laugh at "*some other dark .NET magics.*"

Comment: I just deleted my [myproject].exe.config file and the app would not run without it so it looks like your claim that "Your application will run without its [myproject].exe.config file" is not always true... I thought it would use the embedded settings if the config file is not found but it didn't... Click Once app BTW...

Comment: @DeanK. Interesting. I'd have to dig a bit to see if that was a ClickOnce caveat only. Is there anything in that config file whose absence might just be causing a silent crash? Connection String? etc?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows XP, it's stored in a file called user.config in a subfolder of:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data
```

http://dotnetproject.blogspot.com/2006/08/where-is-userconfig-file-located-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the .settings file in your application? When you add values to that file, an app.config file gets created for you. You should be seeing it in your solution explorer.