# How to change in runtime application settings

Tags: c#, .net, settings.settings

I'm trying to change in runtime one key of my applications settings file, but it does not work.

I do on that way:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["XPTO"] = "HELLO";
```

It seems that it only changes in memory, not on the file.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at my [overview of .NET settings files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481025/where-property-setting-value-stored-in-c-windows-application/481064#481064)...In short, I think you want a user-scoped setting. It will behave more like you expect.

> **Edit:** If you are using the [settings designer in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx), then simply change the "Scope" to "User". If not, you should be able to do the equivalent programmatically.

Comment: Please note that when changing the Settings and saving, the settings won't be changed in the bin folder, but in [userfolder]\Local Settings\Application Data\\[company name]\\[application].exe[hash string]\\[version]\user.config

Comment: In more recent versions of Windows it will be changed on [userfolder]\AppData\Local\\[company name]\\[application].exe[hash string]\\[version]\user.config

Comment: @Jader Yep. I do mention this briefly in my overview and give programmatic ways to retrieve the resulting path. But thanks for sharing these details.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your app has write permissions on the file...

```
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);  // the config that applies to all users
    AppSettingsSection appSettings = config.AppSettings;

    if (appSettings.IsReadOnly() == false)
    {
        appSettings("Key").Value = "new value";

        config.Save();
    }
```

I'm ignoring all the possible exceptions that can be thrown...

Comment: How can I hava access to ConfigurationManager class. I try to use this piece of code and it results in some errors that does not konws that class :S.

Comment: Add System.Configuration as a reference.

Answer (score 5):

The AppSettings file is not designed to be writable.  It is designed to store configurations that will not change at run time but might change over time ie: DB Connection Strings, web service URL's, etc.

So, while it may be possible to update the file in reality you should re-asses if this value should be stored there.