# Error while loading XML file using LINQ & Change the XML file after loading

Tags: xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file as follows.

Filename:myapp.connfig

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  <add key="Key1" value="false" />
    <add key="Key2" value="5893893"/>
    <add key="key3" value="44123"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I want to load this xml file into a datagridview.

I am using Linq to XML but not able to load it.

using Code as below

```
        var q = from c in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("configuration").Elements("appSettings")
                select new
                {
                    myKey = c.Element("add").Attributes("key"),
                    myValue = c.Element("add").Attribute("Value").Value

                };

dataGridView1.DataSource = q.ToList();
```

In the resultset of the query i am getting message as "Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results"".

What is going wrong in above LINQ statement.

Also after loading XML files, I want to edit these values and save back to XML file. How can i accomplish this task.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xml is case sensitive you should use lowercase names of attributes and elements. Also you have wrong elements selection. `configuration` is a root of xml, and you are selecting single `appSettings` element, instead of selecting all `add` elements inside. Here is how query should look:

```
var q = from a in xmlDoc.Descendants("appSettings").Elements("add")
        select new
        {
             myKey = (string)a.Attribute("key"), // also here use Attribute
             myValue = (string)a.Attribute("value")
        };
```

Comment: for the second part of the question...How I can edit these values in data grid view & save back to the xml file?

Comment: @user373083 take a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546229/how-to-change-in-runtime-application-settings

Answer (score 1):

`xmlDoc.Root` already points to `configuration` element, so you can't query for `.Descendants("configuration")`, because it will return no elements.

You should also change your elements/attributes names to proper ones - they are case sensitive.

`(string)XElement` and `(string)XAttribute` is also better then `XElement.Value`, because it works fine even when element/attribute was not found. With `.Value` approach `NullReferenceException` will be thrown in that situation.

```
var q = from c in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("appSettings")
        select new
        {
            myKey = (string)c.Element("add").Attribute("key"),
            myValue = (string)c.Element("add").Attribute("value")

        };
```